# How do I lowercase a field using Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this:

```
{{user.name.toLowerCase()}}
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line X:
...tatus {{user.name.toLowerCase()}}">  
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I created the following helper, but I'm curious if there's a better solution out there.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function(value) {
    if(object) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(value.toLowerCase());
    } else {
        return '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you use `SafeString` here? Any HTML should presumably still be escaped.

Comment: inside the if statement you are checking for undeclared "object" variable, anyways I think it could be rewritten in one line `return (value && typeof value === 'string') ? value.toLowerCase() : '';`

Comment: @PeterPajchl `return (str && typeof str === 'string' && str.toUpperCase()) || ''` faster then ternary operator

Answer (score 81):

As simply explained in the [doc](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase();
});
```

And just use it like this :

```
<h1>By {{toLowerCase author}}</h1>
```

Comment: How do I do this with express-handlebars module, as Handlebars is not defined there

Answer (score 20):

If you're just trying to display some text as lowercased in HTML (regardless of whether or not it's generated by handlebars), you can use CSS and apply [text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) like so:

```
.css-class-here {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Comment: or the opposite: .all-caps {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't hurt to also check and make sure it is a string and if not return nothing.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('lowercase', function (str) {
  if(str && typeof str === "string") {
    return str.toLowerCase();
  }
  return '';
});
```

Usage :

```
// now let's pass a string or variable to our helper
{{lowercase 'MY NAME IS'}}
```

Output :

```
my name is
```

Answer (score 9):

Previous answer from @Eric seems not to work now, my solution is very similar, but probably the definition of helpers changed a little in new versions of handlebars:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('tolower', function(options) {
    return options.fn(this).toLowerCase();
});
```

and in the template

```
<img src="/media/images/modules/{{#tolower}}{{name}}{{/tolower}}.png"...
```

Cheers

Comment: Nice, but using a block helper is overkill, and makes the template harder to read. I think Cyril's answer is better.