# Grunt-Spritesmith: How can I lowercase the file name in the handlebar template?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-spritesmith

I have this:

```
{{#items}}
  .ts-{{name}} { background-position: sprite_position_percentage( {{px.offset_x}}, {{px.offset_y}} ) }
{{/items}}
```

How can I lowecase the `name` variable?

I tried `{{name.toLowerCase()}}` but the output produced was missing the name parameter: `.ts- { background-pos...`

Comment: A good method is described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19836418/2008500)

Comment: I am very new to handlebars, and am not sure how exactly they're wired with grunt spritesmith... where would the code defining the helper go? In the template itself?

Comment: Yes helpers can be defined in the template. Check out [this example template](http://runnable.com/Ulhy_Hlb3_EeAAAW/how-to-use-custom-helpers-methods-handlebars-js-for-javascript-and-jquery). Basically just wrap the helper in a script tag.